# Generate random strings to append to UID

Tags: random, uuid, smalltalk

I prefer to generate uniquely random alpha-numeric string to append to the end of my UID.

The closest I could find in the class library so far has been the Random class, which generates numbers which is the next best thing.

What I have so far is:

```
getNextRandomNumber
^(((rand nextValue) / 
   (Time now milliSeconds asInteger / Time now minutes asInteger 
   + (Time now hour24 asInteger)) asInteger)).
```

`rand` is a class variable, initialized as:

```
initialize
    rand := Random new.
```

This seems very poorly written. But I'm unsure of what else to do.

Comment: try http://smalltalk.gnu.org/blog/sblinn/fun-md5-and-random

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Which dialect are you using?

In Pharo, I usually implement a method in `String class` called something like `#randomOfSize:`. Something like:

```
String class >> randomOfSize: anInteger

^ self streamContents: [ :s | 
    anInteger timesRepeat: 
      [ s nextPut: (Character codePoint: (97 to: 122) atRandom) ] ]
```

You can tweak the character codes to get the interval of characters you need.

Then, to generate an 8 characters long random string you can do:

```
String randomOfSize: 8
```

In Pharo, you can also use the `UUID` class, as follows:

```
UUID new printString
```

Hope it helped!

Comment: This creates a random string with lower case characters only, not an alpha-numeric string. ASCII 97 to 122 is $a to $z.

Comment: So the UUID class... how does it maintain uniqueness? Do I need to worry about that, or is it all automagically handled already? Does your personal implementation handle uniqueness?

Comment: The class comment of the UUID class (Pharo 1.4) says: A class to generate UUID
by John M McIntosh johnmci@smalltalkconsulting.com

See http://www.webdav.org/specs/draft-leach-uuids-guids-01.txt

If a plugin does not exist then we generate a UUID version 4 type GUID; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuid#Version_4_.28random.29

Comment: Ah, thanks! I think this will work nicely - due to the length of version 4 UUID, I can just modify my entries to use the UUID and also have a property for my personal ID of the entry (using '&&' and whatnot). Thanks

Comment: BTW Squeak has the same UUID class.